# When should a datagram socket be connected?

Tags: c, sockets, posix

I am working in C, using the POSIX socket API.

I am not sure when it is appropriate to connect a datagram socket. As I understand it, UDP is connectionless, and SOCK_DGRAM sockets use UDP. So what happens when connect() and accept() are used on datagram sockets?

It seems to me that connecting them and using send()/recv() is easier than not connecting them and using sendto()/recvfrom().

Is there a difference in the functionality of the sockets when connected, or is this just an abstraction?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`connect()` on a datagram socket is appropriate when you want the convenience of a default destination peer for use by `send()`, rather than explicitly specifying a destination with `sendto()`.  There is no functional difference.

`connect()`ing to an AF_UNSPEC address will clear the datagram socket's default peer.  (This last behavior is widely supported, I think, but only [recently formalized](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/connect.html).)

`connect()` on a datagram socket will limits `recv()`s to data originating from the peer.

`accept()` on a datagram socket is an error (EOPNOTSUPP), regardless of "connectedness".

Comment: It does change the meaning of recv. From `man connect`: "If  the  socket  sockfd  is  of  type SOCK_DGRAM then addr is the address to which datagrams are sent by default, and the only address from which datagrams are received."

Comment: @Guido, yes indeed.  Editing.

Comment: Great answer then. I'd add that you "should" connect a DGRAM socket if you only plan to communicate with one other host (socket, to be precise). This might be desirable when streaming video, for example, but not desirable in a P2P network software.